# How to navigate multiple layers of parent-child relationships using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Title is vague and slightly misleading, I apologize. New to rails and this problem is a bit complicated for me to even create a generalized description.

I have an assignment I'm working on where I have 4 tables I'm interacting with, Merchants, Customers, Invoices, and transactions. [Here is a picture of my db schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRQEd.png) and here are my models:

```ruby
class Merchant < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :invoices
    has_many :customers, through: :invoices
    has_many :items
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :invoices
    has_many :merchants, through: :invoices
end

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :merchant
  has_many :transactions
  has_many :invoice_items
  has_many :items, through: :invoice_items
  enum status: [:"in progress", :completed, :cancelled]
end

class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
  enum result: [:success, :failed]
end
```

Transactions have their status be either "success" or "failed" represented by an integer enum "0" or "1", respectively. My objective is to find the top five customers with the most successful transactions for any given merchant using active record queries. So far I haven't been able to find a way to access transactions from merchant or vice versa. I've been able to make some useful code such as finding the top 5 customers amongst all merchants with this:

```
Transaction
.joins(invoice: :customer)
.joins(invoice: :merchant)
.select('customers.*, count(transactions) as total_success')
.where('transactions.result = ?', 1)
.group('customers.id')
.order('total_success DESC')
.limit(5)
```

but any attempt at tying it to a particular merchant_id yields an error since transactions knows nothing about merchants.

I originally interpreted the assignment as just needing to obtain completed invoices and worked out this code which I think could be close but still needs a way to interact with transactions:

```
in the merchant model

self.invoices.group(:customer_id).where(status: 1).count.sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse.first(5)
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. I apologize again if this question has been answered somewhere else but I could barely figure out how to ask it :/

Comment: You might come to regret having a symbol like `:"in progress"` instead of `:in_progress`.

Comment: I didn't notice this at first but I agree with you, unfortunately that part was built into the project already

Answer (score 0):

I would take the Merchant as a starting point instead of the Transaction, since you want to run some logic on any given Merchant.
So I would start with finding the Merchant and include the invoices and their successfull transactions. Something like this:

```rb
merchant =
 Merchant
 .includes(invoices: [:transactions])
 .where(id: 1, transactions: { result: :success } )
```

So this would give you the variable `merchant` which is an array holding 1 Merchant with all it's invoices and successfull transactions. Now you should be able to order the invoices by the number of their transactions(think about `.length`) and grab the first 5 (or last 5 depending on how you order them).
Now with that 5 invoices you can call the customer on it since an invoice belongs_to a customer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Whenever I run this I get an error where I can't convert a symbol into an integer (when trying to do :invoices[:transactions]) nor does it let me use .includes on Merchant.find(1) saying it doesn't work on objects of that class. I'm trying to run this in rails console, would that be the issue?

Comment: I edited my answer. This should give you a better result.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped, I was able to work out the answer from this